# Как в php работать с несколькими submit?

Tags: php, php5

Делал так:

Есть такой код:

```
 $submit1 = $_POST["submit1"];
 $submit2 = $_POST["submit2"];

if(isset($submit1)){
    echo "111";
}elseif(isset($submit2)){
    echo "222";
}
```

Но ничего хорошего не произошло,т.е. submit не передает значение по условию, а без условии передает. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 4):

```
<form method="post">
  ...
  <input type="submit" name="save" value="Сохранить" />
  <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Удалить" />
</form>


if (isset($_POST['save'])) {
  ...
}
else if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  ...
}
```